# What's the probability of a probability?

Tags: probability

Imagine there is a type of pepper such that $1$ in $10$ of these peppers are spicy.

Now imagine picking $10$ of these peppers at random. The probability states that $1$ in $10$ of these peppers are spicy, but it is not guaranteed that exactly one of these ten peppers need to be spicy.

Picking $10$ of these peppers at random, what is the probability that $1$ in $10$ of them are spicy?

Comment: Hint, for one particular pepper to be spicy, this is the probability that that pepper is spicy and all others are non-spicy.  Then, there are 10 ways that this can happen.

More general hint, you can use the binomial distribution.

Comment: "The probability states that 1  in 10 of these peppers are spicy" No, it doesn't.

Comment: @leonbloy Yeah, sorry about that, I just couldn't think of a better way to say "in theory, 1 in 10 of these peppers should be spicy"

Comment: To be precise, one should say something to the effect of "The probability that a single pepper is spicy is $1/10$". One then separates the potential confusion of the 10 relating to the probability of a single pepper and the 10 relating to the number of peppers sampled.

Answer (score 3):

The event that exactly one is spicy, is the union of the events

$$E_1 \equiv \text{the first item spicy, the rest aren't}$$
$$E_2 \equiv \text{the second item spicy, the rest aren't}$$
$$\cdots$$

The probability of each one is $P(E_i) = \frac{1}{10} (\frac{9}{10})^9$

Because these events are exclusive and equiprobable, the total probability is

$$P=10 \frac{1}{10} \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^9 = \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^9 = 0.387\cdots$$

This a particular case of the Binomial distribution.

If instead of $n=10$ you have a larger number:

$$P= n \frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n-1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n(n-1)/n} \approx e^{-1+1/n}\approx \frac{1}{e}=0.3678794411\cdots$$

Caveat: this assumes that each item is independent from the rest.

BTW: the question title makes little sense. This is a plain probability (i.e., the probability of a event).

Comment: Well, the title kind of makes sense, assuming that afterward we are going to choose one of the ten peppers. It's the probability that that an event occurs (that exactly one in ten is spicy) such that the subsequent conditional probability of choosing the spicy pepper is 10%.